# db2 compare year and month side by side

Tags: sql, db2

I need to compare side by side the companies values by current year vs last year and current month with same month of the previous year.

I use this query to get the values

```
SELECT STORE, SUM(TOTAL) as VAL, DATE FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE DATE=CURRENT_DATE GROUP BY STORE ORDER BY STORE
```

below the results

```
STORE  |  VAL  |  DATE
  1       10      CURRENT_DATE (2018-27-03)
  1       20      2018-26-03
  1       30      2018-25-03
  2       20      CURRENT_DATE (2018-27-03)
  2       20      2018-26-02
```

and i need this

```
STORE  | VALUE CURRENT YEAR | VALUE LAST YEAR      
1        60                   30 (CALCULATED)    
2        40                   50 (CALCULATED)

STORE  | VALUE CURRENT MONTH | VALUE SAME MONTH OF LAST YEAR 
1        60                    30 (CALCULATED)      
2        20                    50 (CALCULATED)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could just join two sub-selects together.

E.g with this DDL and Data

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (STORE int,  VAL int, D DATE);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES
 ( 1, 10, '2018-03-27')
,( 1, 20, '2018-03-26')
,( 1, 10, '2018-02-25')
,( 1, 35, '2017-03-25')
,( 2, 20, '2018-03-27')
,( 2, 15, '2017-03-26');
```

This will get you current month and last month last year values

```
SELECT C.*, LY.VAL_CURR_MONTH_LY
FROM (
    SELECT STORE, SUM(VAL) as VAL_CURR_MONTH
    FROM MYTABLE WHERE INT(D)/100=INT(CURRENT_DATE)/100
    GROUP BY STORE ) AS C
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT STORE
    ,       SUM(VAL) AS VAL_CURR_MONTH_LY
    FROM MYTABLE
     WHERE INT(D)/100 = INT(CURRENT_DATE)/100 -100
     GROUP BY STORE ) LY
ON
    C.STORE = LY.STORE
```

Then this for years

```
SELECT C.*, LY.VAL_LY
FROM (
    SELECT STORE, SUM(VAL) as VAL_CURR_YEAR
    FROM MYTABLE WHERE INT(D)/10000=INT(CURRENT_DATE)/10000
    GROUP BY STORE ) AS C
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT STORE
    ,       SUM(VAL) AS VAL_LY
    FROM MYTABLE
     WHERE INT(D)/10000 = INT(CURRENT_DATE)/10000 -1
     GROUP BY STORE ) LY
ON
    C.STORE = LY.STORE
```

P.S. there are many other ways to manipulate dates, but casting to INT is maybe one of the easier ways

Also, here is a more flexible way to get the "Same Month of Last Year" value. A similar method can get "last Year" values.

```
SELECT T.*
,      AVG(VAL) OVER(
        PARTITION BY STORE 
        ORDER BY YEAR_MONTH
        RANGE BETWEEN 101 PRECEDING AND 100 PRECEDING
       ) AS SAME_MONTH_PREV_YEAR
FROM 
(   SELECT STORE
    ,      INTEGER(D)/100 AS YEAR_MONTH
    ,      SUM(VAL) AS VAL
    FROM    
        MYTABLE T
    GROUP BY
           STORE
    ,      INTEGER(D)/100
) AS T
;
```

Gives

```
 STORE YEAR_MONTH VAL SAME_MONTH_PREV_YEAR
 ----- ---------- --- --------------------
     1     201703  35                 NULL
     1     201802  10                 NULL
     1     201803  30                   35
     2     201703  15                 NULL
     2     201803  20                   15
```

Comment: No, casting to `INT` is **not** one of the easier ways of manipulating dates.  The easier way is using one of the myriad date/time functions the platform provides - although it's almost always better to avoid functions on searched columns, since that usually prevents the use of an index to fulfill the query.

Comment: I'm not sure anything is easy when it comes to SQL and date manipulation... but yes you make valid points.  Certainly using YEAR() would be the better in the second query. Plus Db2 will re-write e.g. `where year(d) = 2018` as `'01/01/2018' <= Q1.D AND Q1.D <= '31/12/2018'` when optimizing which it does not do with the INT() method

Comment: Although you do need to use the INT method if you want to use the  `RANGE BETWEEN` on dates with OLAP functions as in my last example

Comment: `db2 "explain plan for select * from d where year(d) = 2018"`  `db2exfmt -1 -d $DATABASE 2>&1 | grep 2018\'`  shows `('01/01/2018' <= Q1.D)` and `(Q1.D <= '31/12/2018')`

Comment: Interesting to note, and something I've known was possible (although I wonder how it handles multiple `AND`/`OR`s and timestamps).  However, that `RANGE BETWEEN` setup would more likely be better handled via `LAG()`

Comment: LAG() is OK if you know you don't have gaps - i.e. if a store was closed for a month (or a year) and had no sales, then LAG() might pick up the wrong months data.  On the re-write, that will happen regardless of other clauses. It does work on YEAR(timestamp_column) too, and also if you do eg. `YEAR(d) = 2018 AND MONTH(d) = 03`.  Does not work for CURRENT_DATE though, it needs literal values

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid functions on table columns in where clauses.  Check following SQLs which are based on  P. Vernon sample table.

Note: These SQLs are for DB2 LUW 11.1

For month:

```
SELECT STORE, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(D) = year(current date) THEN val 
                ELSE 0 END) as VAL_CURR_MONTH, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(D) = year(current date) - 1 THEN vaL 
                ELSE 0 END) as VAL_CURR_MONTH_LY
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE D between first_day(current date) and last_day(current date)
      or D between first_day(current date - 1 year) and last_day(current date - 1 year) 
GROUP BY STORE 
ORDER BY STORE
```

For year:

```
SELECT STORE, SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(D) = year(current date) THEN val
                       ELSE 0 END) as VAL_CY, 
              SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(D) = year(current date) - 1 THEN vaL
                       ELSE 0 END) as VAL_LY
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE D between first_day(current date - (month(current date) - 1) months) 
                and last_day(current date + (12 - month(current date)) months)
      or D between first_day(current date - (month(current date) - 1) months - 1 year) 
                   and last_day(current date + (12 - month(current date)) months - 1 year) 

GROUP BY STORE 
ORDER BY STORE
```

Comment: [Please avoid the use of `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  In particular, if the 'year' was supposed to be "previous 12 months" (as opposed to year-to-date, which is what you have here), the calculation becomes a much more parseable `< FIRST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + 12 MONTHS`.  If the asker really wants year-to-date, it's going to be more readable to go from a string: `< DATE(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) || '-01-01') + 12 MONTHS`.

Comment: Thanks for the link for "use of BETWEEN". I read the article. I still consider that there is nothing wrong in use of BETWEEN.